# getenv() returning environment as null?

Tags: c, shell

I am trying to print the executables in the current directory in c and bash with the following code:

```
system("EXEC_PATH=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable)");
printf("executables are: %s\n", getenv("EXEC_PATH"));
```

However, when I compile and run the c code, the result I get is:

```
executables are: (null)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: that's not how that works. `system` creates a subprocess and any changes to the environment variable belong to the child process and therefore not visible in the program that called `system`

Comment: Ah thats why :/. Is there anyway I can get the binary files in my current directory you would recommend?

Comment: If you want to find executables in the present working directory, suggest you use `getdirentries(2)` or `opendir(3)` (better probably) to loop through them and use `stat(2)` to figure out if a file is executable.

Comment: the other way would be to use popen, which will let you read the results of the `find`'s output and you can then use that to do whatever you like

Comment: Yes I used popen and fgets to get my executables. Thanks! Can you post your solution so that more can see?

Answer (score 2):

`system()` is creating a new shell and setting the environment in there and then throwing it away when that shell exits.

`getenv()` is using the environment of the "current" process.

Try getting the result of the system call and using `putenv` to modify the current environment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Ahmed Masud's solution with popen and fgets and got a working solution:

```
    char buff[BUFSIZ];
    char elf_arr
    FILE *fp = popen("find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable","r");
    while (fgets( buff, BUFSIZ, fp ) != NULL ) {
            printf("executables are: %s\n", buff);
    }
    pclose(fp);
```